# Autofilter the already Autofilterd column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, autofilter

I am using a custom Autofilter by use of a `dictionary` as in the below code.
Now, I need to set an **additional autofilter** on the **already filtered column**.
e.g. the result of the first autofilter is ("`ID 20 , Name30 , Color 35 , ID39`"),
on the second autofilter, I need to filter for a string contains e.g. "`*30*`".
I need to do it in a second separate step, I mean, after placing the first filter in the way I tried and then I closed that workbook completely (to be eloquent), I need then to apply the second filter on the already filtered range, by cells containing *30*. or meaning apply filter on the data found on the visible cells only.
**Note**, I do not prefer to use a a helper column/sheet ,
and also want to keep my code as it is, meaning I seek for additional sub.
In advance, great thanks for your time of help.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Filter_the_Filtered_Column()

    Const filter_Column As Long = 2
    
    Dim filter_Criteria() As Variant
    filter_Criteria = Array("*Id*", "*Name*", "*Color*")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.UsedRange.Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1)  '(UsedRange except the first Row)
    
    Dim rCount As Long, arr() As Variant, dict As Object, el, r As Long
    rCount = rg.Rows.count - 1
    arr = rg.Columns(filter_Column).Resize(rCount).Offset(1).value         'Write the values from criteria column to an array.
        
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")                        'Write the matching strings to the keys (a 1D array) of a dictionary.
 
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)                                                'Loop through the elements of the array.
        For Each el In filter_Criteria
            If arr(r, 1) Like el Then dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString: Exit For
        Next el
    Next r
    
    If dict.count > 0 Then
        rg.AutoFilter Field:=filter_Column, Criteria1:=dict.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues   'use the keys of the dictionary (a 1D array) as a Criteria
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use the same logic? Just check what the current values in the filtered column are with the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and then set your dictionary again with a check for those values `Like "30"`.

Comment: @Notus_Panda , I can not load the filtered range into an Array

Comment: Do you need to do it **in a second step**? I mean, after placing the first filter in the way you try and apply it on the already filtered range? Then, you need to filter by "30", or by cells **containing 30**?

Comment: If I would say that the final result to show only the rows having cells in the second column containing "30" string, but previously being filtered according to `filter_Criteria`, would it be a correct understanding?  Now, should the solution extend your existing code (working on it, in a second step) or should another piece of code to be run after the first one?

Comment: Why not convert the original range to a recordset (see https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/) - create a 2nd recordset with a filter on the first, then filter the 2nd recordset based on your next criteria

Comment: "I can not load the filtered range into an Array" - you can write a pretty simple function to return an array from a filtered range....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want it as a separated sub, you can try this:

```
Sub filteredRangeToArray()
    Const filter_Column As Long = 2
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr(), rng As Range, newSh As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, r As Long
    Dim nFilter As String: nFilter = "30"
    Dim dict As Object
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set newSh = Worksheets.Add
    rng.Copy newSh.Range("A1")
    arr = newSh.Range("A1:A" & rng.Count).Value
    newSh.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(r, 1) Like nFilter Then dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString
    Next r
    
    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        rg.AutoFilter Field:=filter_Column, Criteria1:=dict.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues   'use the keys of the dictionary (a 1D array) as a Criteria
    End If
End Sub
```

But now that I see FaneDuru's comment about making the dict a global variable, it could be a lot faster/easier of course. I'll leave my answer for when you don't want to use that.

**Edit:**

```
Sub filteredRangeToArray_V2()
    Const filter_Column As Long = 2
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr(), rng As Range, newSh As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, r As Long
    Dim nFilter As String: nFilter = "*30*"
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim ccell As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Offset(0, filter_Column - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Count)
    r = 1
    For Each ccell In rng.Cells
        arr(r) = ccell.Value
        r = r + 1
    Next ccell
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(r) Like nFilter Then dict(arr(r)) = vbNullString
    Next r
    
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange.Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    rng.Select
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=filter_Column, Criteria1:=dict.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues   'use the keys of the dictionary (a 1D array) as a Criteria
    End If
End Sub
```

This should accommodate the not needing another sheet/helper-column.

Comment: It  dose not work as your answer formulated. I changed value of `nFilter` to be contains asterisks `"*30*"` and works. thanks but I still seek for an answer without any helper range.

Comment: If you found a way to put `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` directly into an array without using a helper column/sheet , then your answer will be brilliant.

Comment: Sadly, the workaround is needed if you don't want to use a global variant as FaneDuru suggested. Trying to get a non-contiguous range in one go to an array just simply gives an error. You were right on the `*30*`. What you can do is read the values of the rng to a dictionary/array and work from there. I'll see if I can make an edit.

Comment: See my edit, is this more what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

A little busy and no time to wait for answers to my clarification questions, sorry...

It looks enough to change:

```
     For r = 1 To UBound(arr)                                                'Loop through the elements of the array.
        For Each el In filter_Criteria
            If arr(r, 1) Like el Then dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString: Exit For
        Next el
    Next r
```

with:

```
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)                                                
        For Each El In filter_Criteria
            If arr(r, 1) Like El And arr(r, 1) Like Second_filter Then dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString: Exit For
        Next El
    Next r
```

Of course, `Second_filter` is a string variable keeping your wished one ("30")...

Even if it would be run after the first filter (as a result of your existing code), it will work as a second step, too.

If you want it being even faster, you can declare `dict` as a global variable (on top of the module) and delete the declaration from your existing code.

Then, use it in the second step, to filter in another dictionary...

To do that, please test the next code:

```
Sub Filter_the_Filtered_Column_After()
    Const filter_Column As Long = 2
    Dim Second_filter As String: Second_filter = "*30*"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.UsedRange.Resize(ws.UsedRange.rows.count - 1).Offset(1)  '(UsedRange except the first Row)
    
    Dim r As Long, dict2 As Object
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")                        'Write the matching strings to the keys (a 1D array) of a dictionary.
 
    For r = 0 To UBound(dict.keys)                                         'Loop through the elements of the array.
        If dict.keys()(r) Like Second_filter Then dict2(dict.keys()(r)) = vbNullString
    Next r

    If dict.count > 0 Then
        rg.AutoFilter field:=filter_Column, Criteria1:=dict2.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues   'use the keys of the dictionary (a 1D array) as a Criteria
    End If

End Sub
```

Of course, you should preliminarily check if `not dict is nothing`, in case of running the above code without loading the dictionary, or an error has been raised in an intermediary procedure run in the mean time and you had to close it...

**Edited**:

In order to extract the filter used array, if you do not know it (as you asked in a comment, please use the next function:

```
Function extractFiltCriteria(sht As Worksheet, filtCol As Long) As Variant
    Dim arrFilt(), i As Long, fltRange As String
    
    With sht.AutoFilter
        fltRange = .Range.address
        With .Filters
            With .Item(filtCol)
                If .On Then
                    If IsArray(.Criteria1) Then
                        If .Operator = xlFilterValues Then
                            If IsArray(.Criteria1) Then extractFiltCriteria = Array(fltRange, .Criteria1, .Operator): Exit Function
                        End If
                    Else
                        ReDim arrFilt(1)
                        If .Criteria1 <> "" Then arrFilt(0) = .Criteria1
                        If .Criteria2 <> "" Then
                            arrFilt(1) = .Criteria2
                        Else
                            ReDim Preserve arrFilt(0)
                        End If
                            extractFiltCriteria = Array(fltRange, arrFilt, xlFilterValues): Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End With
    End With
    
    extractFiltCriteria = Array("") 'no any filter...
End Function
```

It can be use in the next adapted code:

```
Sub Filter_the_Filtered_Column2()
   Dim filter_Criteria(), ws As Worksheet
   Const col As Long = 2, Second_filter As String = "*30*"
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   
   If ws.AutoFilterMode = False Then MsgBox "No filter applied...": Exit Sub
   filter_Criteria = extractFiltCriteria(ws, col) 'extract filtered range, filter array and filter Operator
   If filter_Criteria(0) = "" Then MsgBox "No filter applied...": Exit Sub 

    Dim dict As Object, arr, El, mtch, r As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    arr = ws.Range(filter_Criteria(0)).Value2 'place in the array the extracted range which was previously filtered
    
    For r = 2 To UBound(arr)
        mtch = Application.match("=" & arr(r, col), filter_Criteria(1), 0)            'check if the array element matches the extracted filtering array
        If Not IsError(mtch) Then
            If arr(r, col) Like Second_filter Then dict(arr(r, col)) = vbNullString 'if a match exists and the array element contains Second_filter string
        End If
    Next r
     
     'refilter by the new dict.keys array:
    ws.Range(filter_Criteria(0)).AutoFilter col, dict.keys, Operator:=filter_Criteria(2)
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback. It should be extremely fast...

But the function treats exactly the case: array filter in the second column. It can be developed to fulfill all possible cases, but it will be much more complicated...

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253648/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-autofilter-the-already-autofilterd-column); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Sure I am speaking about your updated code. if there are no cases of the second criteria matching then `Debug.print dict.count = 0`

Comment: the  (error '13': Type mismatch) can be easily fixed by count `dict.keys` before applying the filter (`If dict.count > 0 Then`) . Now there is still one issue (as cited before) if I run your code twice on the same session ,I got "No filter applied..." related to this line If `filter_Criteria(0) = "".....`. also I do not understand this part `Operator:=filter_Criteria(2)`

Comment: @Soma OK. For the case of only two values matching that `Second_filter` string, VBA does not recognize `Criteria1` as an array. It 'translate' somehow the fact in two criteria (1 and 2) with `xlOr` operator. But I will adapt the (function) code to place both of them in an array and use `xlFilterValues` operator. Now, `Operator:=filter_Criteria(2)` is the third parameter of the array which means `xlFilterValues` (7) for the array and 'xlOr` for both criteria used. I could use the way VBA see the facts, but to do the things in the same way (using an array), artificially the function to return 7.

Comment: @Soma Please, use the updated function. It should do what I tried suggesting in the above comment. No time to test it, I need to leave home again, but I think it will work as it should...

Comment: @Soma No need to admit that, it is not true, anyhow... But I would like you to admit that your question was bad in terms of clearly describing the need. Then, promise to be more attentive next time and even more important admit that you made a mistake. For instance, if you would say something like "Yes, it was not so clear but what about the case of dealing with a previously closed workbook not knowing the filtering array", I could show you the solution from that time. I always try using as much as possible from the OP shown code. I bring something new if no possible to use what he has...

Comment: no problem, I have deleted my last comment. (with no offence) But I see you always persist on your opinion. If my question was bad and not clear enough , So can you explain How  the other person ("Notus_Panda") successfully understood me and provided a working solution before you can do. Some people here (ST) do not like the big question. Anyhow, promise to be more attentive next time.

Comment: @Soma What? That solution was a standard one, you could also do it, as I mentioned in a previous comment, I answered when of your question showing how to proceed (by iteration). Loading an array by iteration and **then** using it to load a dictionary is at least strange, anyhow. You said: "also want to keep my code as it is, meaning I seek for additional sub". This 'told' me something and **all my proposed solutions looked for an efficient solution using arrays**. And one last requirement: I would like to not send me links to your questions, anymore. I like helping only a specific kind of user

Comment: Ok no problem at all, and promise I will never send links for your and never asking for your help again.

Comment: Anyhow, I wish to tell you many thanks for all your last helps.